# Index performance degrades unless they are rebuilt routinely

Tags: oracle, database-performance, oracle9i

I have Oracle 9i on Oracle 9iAS with Forms 6i on a virtual environment. Performance remains good for 2-4 hours when we rebuild the index, but degrades after while. Then we rebuild, then performance better. Kindly tell where to look for consistent and improved performance.

I tried `dbms_stats.gather_table_stats` and `analyze` commands but the issue remains the same.

```
SELECT 'EXEC dbms_stats.gather_table_stats (ownname => ''&A'', tabname => '''||table_name || ''' ,partname => NULL ,cascade => TRUE);'
FROM USER_TABLES;

SELECT 'ALTER INDEX ' || INDEX_NAME || ' REBUILD COMPUTE STATISTICS; ' 
FROM USER_INDEXES;
```

Comment: What is going on during the 2-4 hours after you rebuild your index?

Comment: Insertion/deletion/updating  of records to tables.process of records etc.

Comment: If you delete most of the rows from the table and then insert and then modify, then this degrades the index. Before loading a large number of rows, it is recommended to remove indexes and create indexes again.

Comment: What type of index?

Comment: the types of indexes used are the Bitmap and Unique index.